# Vue ssr route.params are being taken from another request

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-ssr

I'm using Akryum/vue-cli-plugin-ssr with vue-cli. 
Have a weird behavior on my vue ssr application. Route params are being taken from another request that had been made before that one or maybe in parallel with this.

For example, if I open two pages with different route params and will fastly refresh both of them, first-page route param could be taken from the second page and vice-versa.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed that by replacing route.path if it doesn't equal to request.path, but if anyone knows better solutions, please write it here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough context to figure out the issue. Seems like you are polluting Vue instance with all request. Most probably you `new Vue()` instance is singleton, i.e. in each node/server request, you are using same instance of Vue.